# how to disable the question (Do you want to ignore battery optimization?) android studio

Tags: android, optimization, message, sleep, battery

I was having problem whit android media player because when I turn off the screen the system goes to sleep mode and stop it and I didnt want that because nobody wants to listen music and have the screen on (who do that?).

I noticed that the problem was on the battery optimizations because if the mobile was plug to power cable it keeps the music playin even if it goes to sleep mode.

I tried with a lot of posibilities to fix it (reading android documentation and trying every thing I was finding in the net) but what works was this code:

```
public void doPower() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        String packageName = getActivity().getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            try {
                //some device doesn't has activity to handle this intent
                //so add try catch
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is: The app at the beginning shows an alert asking the user to disable the battery optimizations and I dont want that, because some users may thinks "this is a bad thing" or "why its asking this?" Because an app like spotify doesnt do it.

How can I avoid the alert message?  If I cant, how can I add something else to the message? (something like this: "So you will able to listen the radio with the screen turn off")

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: Are you using `MediaPlayer` or some other API for playing your audio?

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid that dialog and asking to avoid battery optimizations is absolutely not needed.

What is needed is a wakelock, as described in the [MediaPlayer Using wake locks documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#wakelocks):

> When designing applications that play media in the background, the device may go to sleep while your service is running. Because the Android system tries to conserve battery while the device is sleeping, the system tries to shut off any of the phone's features that are not necessary, including the CPU and the WiFi hardware. However, if your service is playing or streaming music, you want to prevent the system from interfering with your playback.
>
> In order to ensure that your service continues to run under those conditions, you have to use "wake locks." A wake lock is a way to signal to the system that your application is using some feature that should stay available even if the phone is idle.

If you're using `MediaPlayer`, this only requires you use the [`setWakeMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setWakeMode(android.content.Context,%20int)) method:

```
mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

(Note the additional note on the documentation page about holding a [wifi lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#createWifiLock(java.lang.String)) if you're streaming your media from the network.)

Comment: But I alredy did that (setWakeMode and wifi lock) and it still stops the music. Maybe there is another feature to disable. I dont know what to do..    powerManager = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
       wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "mylock");              mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);